# How do I find Windows users and groups who have sysadmin access to SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-10

Is there a query I can run against SQL Server Express database to identify which Windows users and groups have been granted sysadmin rights?

I have an application installer that is installing SQL Server Express on Windows 10 laptops, then creating a database by connecting using Windows authentication.

To make that work, we've always said that the logged-in user has had to be the local administrator. Unfortunately, after a recent Windows update, the "administrator" user is gone.

Unfortunately, the SQL Server Express installation has 'sa' disabled, so we can't connect using it. So the question is, which logins or groups have sysadmin permissions within the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sys.server_principals` table it has a list of all users along with useful information that could be useful.

```
 select * from master.sys.server_principals
```

If you want to list users based on their permissions groups, use `sys.server_role_members` table.

```
select * from master.sys.server_role_members
```

JOIN them to list all users that have been granted a sysadmin rights :

```
select * from master.sys.server_principals sp
JOIN master.sys.server_role_members sr ON sr.member_principal_id = sp.principal_id
WHERE 
    sr.role_principal_id = 3
```